# Declaring variable in WITH expression (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server

is there a way to define a variable inside a WITH expression? Something like:

```
;WITH SomeName AS ( 
    declare @somevar decimal
    set @somevar = ...
    SELECT ....)
```

Possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, you would need to declare / set it outside of the CTE

```
DECLARE @somevar DECIMAL
;WITH SomeName AS (SELECT....)
SELECT @somevar = ...
FROM SomeName
```

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

> CTE_query_definition
>   Specifies a
>   SELECT statement whose result set
>   populates the common table expression.
>   The SELECT statement for
>   CTE_query_definition must meet the
>   same requirements as for creating a
>   view, except a CTE cannot define
>   another CTE.

Comment: A CTE should *return rows*. I don't think you can use it for assigning variables at all.

Comment: @Andriy M - yes, a CTE must return a resultset. You can assign values into variables FROM the CTE though per above - you just can't do it within the CTE

Comment: I thought the assignment was part of the CTE, didn't notice at first that you placed the 'definition' on the same line with `WITH`. I'm so ashamed. Sorry.

Comment: @Andriy M - no need to apologise :)

Answer (score 6):

I've had to use the following approach a few times as a work-around (for example using R-Server in t-sql as the input_data_1 expression; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/quickstart-r-inputs-and-outputs?view=sql-server-2017). The following illustrates the example:

```
WITH ctename (varname) as (
    SELECT MAX(somevar) FROM sometable
)
SELECT *
    FROM someothertable a
    JOIN ctename b on 1=1
    WHERE a.col1 > b.varname;
```

Answer (score -4):

I know this is now an old question, but it is possible to approximate "variable" behaviour using a CTE and judicious application of a CROSS JOIN to harness the power of set-based processing.

```
WITH CTE_Name (somevar1, somevar2)
AS (SELECT 0.15, 0.65)
SELECT
    sq.Col1 * cte.somevar1 AS Calc1,
    sq.Col2 * cte.somevar2 AS Calc2
FROM (
    SELECT 10 Col1, 20 Col2
    UNION SELECT 30, 40
) AS sq
CROSS JOIN CTE_Name AS cte
```

Note that the use of a CROSS JOIN returns the Cartesian product of the tables involved in the join, so to avoid excessive/duplicate rows in the final output, the CTE must return one and ONLY one record.